# Use appcache with Chrome frame (or detect that it doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, offline, html5-appcache, google-chrome-frame

We are building a web-application that will be used offline, using the Application Cache (and a lot more stuffs).

The thing is, we wanted to ask our users with old IEs to use Google Chrome Frame, hoping it will work. But the appcache does not seems to work : although the site is cached correctly, visiting our site without internet connection fails. We get with the standard ie no-network error page.

I found [this FAQ](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/differences-between-chrome-and-chrome-frame#TOC-AppCache) saying that as Chrome Frame relies on IE's network stack, appcache will not work "as expected".

With that in mind, I have little hope to make it work (yet, if you have a solution, feel free to share), my concern is more about detecting this problem to adapt my site's behaviour accordingly.

How can I detect Chrome Frame lack's of support for appcache while the javascript object `window.applicationCache` is still present ?